# Adding Prefix To All Messages Written To Java Standard Output

Tags: java, logging

How can I make it such that everything written to standard output has a date/time prefix?

More background. My application writes to log files through log4j2, but we also have another log file, call it CatchAll.log, that is sort of a "catch all" for all non-logger output. This file will often contain Java garbage collector output, calls to System.out.println(), and other stuff. CatchAll.log doesn't have a nice prefix like "[May 7, 2035 16:03:22]" though, so I often find error messages in there with no way to determine when they happened.

**[Edit]**

Also, CatchAll.log is generated by a process manager. I'm not in control of the process manager's code and I can't migrate off.

I'm going on the assumption that this file gets all of standard output, but I'm not sure.

Comment: How are you creating the `CatchAll.log` file?

Comment: Depending on the application server you are using there will exist numerous options to do that (as well as standard jvm options to enable i.e. gc logs). And more generally a nice log4j2 or logback xml configuration is able to do the trick.

Comment: CatchAll.log is generated by a process manager. I'm not in control of the process manager's code and I can't migrate off.


Also, to give an idea of my depth of knowledge here, I'm going on the assumption that this file gets all of standard output, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have already written something that redirects System.out to a file. If so you should be able to manipulate the data stream however you want. For example, you could inspect the data stream and whenever you see a new line you could set a new line flag and when more content is received write out your prefix before writing that new data.

As a slightly more complicated alternative, instead of doing the formatting yourself you could pass the data to one of the Log4j2 Logger methods. In that case the PatternLayout could be used to format the message. You would also want to make sure not to use the ConsoleAppender writing to System.out in your log4j2.xml or you would end up in and endless loop.

Comment: That's true, but I left out that CatchAll.log is generated by a process manager. I'm not in control of the process manager's code and I can't migrate off so I guess I was thinking about adding a hack by adding an interceptor or something if Java has a way you can configure that.

Thank's for the help

Comment: Java does allow System.out to be redirected. As I stated, that is what I guessed you were doing. If you are using something that wraps your application then you can do exactly what I stated in my answer from inside the app, except you can continue to let it flow to System.out.  All you do is get the outputStream System.out points to then set System.out to point to an OutputStream you control and then as the data comes in on that stream modify it before sending it to the original System.out OutputStream.

Comment: Oh that's great. Thanks a lot.